# Visual Studio keeps getting an old reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an issue in which I copied 2 folders out of a Class Library Server to 2 different Class Libraries.

The issue is when I try to make a reference to those 2 new Class Libraries from a Console Application.

After I add a reference, it seems that the objects still wants to be taken from the old path. I rebuilt in both Debug and Release at least 20 times, in every different combination.

I'm using VS 2013 professional.

Comment: Try cleaning your solution.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean, then a rebuild?

Comment: tried, both server and console application. no change.

Comment: Copying in file system and then referencing in VS is the definition of "Hell" in the dictionary. Create new ones and copy files if you can.

Comment: i figured copying the files makes the problems, probably pointers stuff..but i actually know that there must be some other way.

Comment: I'd open the .csproj file in a text editor and search for the old (wrong) path. If you find any change them to the new (correct) path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes old question but maybe this will help someone!

Check if one of the packages you installed modified the binding redirects in `app.config` or `web.config`.  This happened to me and wasted a morning.